# Duda con las limitaciones de campos personalizados y multilenguaje nativo en joomla

Tags: joomla3

Bueno tal como dice el título. No uso joomla desde su versión 3.2 , Ahora estoy en un proyecto multilenguaje con la última versión, le instalé un CCK (k2), falang (para traducir campos en k2), y el advanced module manager.

Mi duda surge porque me he pasado más tiempo googleando soluciones a problemas generados con falang o por su escases de opciones gratuitas o con k2 con el multilenguaje.

Siempre use joomla con sus opciones nativas de multilenguaje y me resultan más cómodas, mi pregunta es ahora que joomla tiene campos personalizados me será tan necesario usar K2?? . Solo estaría agregando campos basicos para un panel de usuarios, panel de traducción y cambiar un poco la plantilla de ciertas secciones.

Para ser más preciso podría conseguir esto solo usando los campos personalizados de joomla, el multilenguaje nativo y los templates overrade? Cuales son las limitaciones frente a k2 y falang respecto a los campos y asociaciones?

Edit: Mejore la pregunta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La pregunta casi que es basada en opiniones, por lo que voy a orientar la respuesta para que sea lo más neutral y objetiva posible:

- Joomla es multilingüe desde la versión 3.7 (o antes), por lo cual NO es necesario (en la mayoría de los casos) utilizar una extensión como Falang para traducir contenido ni extensiones. La única excepción es cuando una extensión fue mal hecha y no se adapta a las convenciones de Joomla para que sea multilingüe de forma nativa.
- Los campos personalizados (nativos) en los artículos de Joomla son bastante flexibles y variados en general, por lo cual, un sitio básico no debería requerir ningún CCK adicional (como K2). En caso que requieras algún tipo de campo personalizado que no tenga Joomla, podrías considerar primero si vale la pena utilizar un CCK solo por eso, o si creas la extensión tú mismo, o si adaptas tu proyecto para que funcione con las opciones que ofrece el *core* de Joomla.
- Los override de templates no son una mala práctica en Joomla, puesto que no son más que una modificación del código, y de hecho puede ayudarte en la solución de algunos inconvenientes, o en la mejora de cómo manejas cierta información, o cómo la muestras a tus usuarios.
- Utilizar o no Advanced Module Manager está fuera del alcance de la respuesta, puesto que se basa en opiniones. Es cierto que el administrador de módulos de Joomla no tiene tantas opciones como dicha extensión, pero sirve igualmente.